# How to throw exception or handle filter condition in webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

```
1 customerRepo.findById(customerId) // finding the Customer
2               .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(
                        () -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("not found")))) // if empty throw error
3               .filter(customer -> StringUtils.isEmpty(customer.getType().equals("Regular"))) // add filter condition

4               .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(
                        () -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("no regualar customer")))) // If empty throw error
                        
5               flatMap....... (logic continues)
```

1. Finding the customer based on ID from DB.
2. Throwing error if no customer is found for the cutomer ID.
3. Check if Regular customer is there.
4. If no regular customer then throw exception with different messsage.
5. then I have further logic to continue.

**Question:**

1. Is this the correct way to write in complete reactive.
2. I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: error at line 4 when I hit continously. ( **Note**: I am not getting RuntimeException line 2 if Customer is not there)
3. Need help with proper way to write the logic.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the correct way to write in complete reactive.

Nothing inherently wrong with the pattern you've used there. Just two things that come to mind:

- `Mono.defer()` doesn't really add anything here - you may as well just pass a standard `Mono.error()` containing your exception in both cases.
- If you can do without the custom exceptions, then you can just use the `single()` method instead which will return a standard `NoSuchElementException` if nothing is there.

> I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: error at line 4 when I hit continously. ( Note: I am not getting RuntimeException line 2 if Customer is not there)

That must mean that your filter condition in line 3 is always filtering out the value - you wouldn't get that runtime exception thrown otherwise.

Comment: Sure, but I want different message for line 4 and line 2, so I need to use custom message.
If line 4 condition satisfies, I am getting exception trace in logs though in line 2 there is no exception trace..

But the functionality is working as expected.